# How to find an executable file path in c#

Tags: c#, path, executable

I am trying to build a code that saves paths of applications in an access database.How can i get the path of the executable file?

Comment: is that a windows application?

Comment: Did Google hide all the results from you?

Comment: "Please search 'How do I paste the title of my question into Google?' and tell me the results." Literally the first hit on Google for your title is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```